# What should be the rating for this app?

Tags: ios, app-store, rating

I'm showing a business website in simple `UIWebView`. When I'm trying to upload it to AppStore, they asked me to select rating for this app. I've selected NO for all other points except this, **Unrestricted Web Access**.

If I choose YES then, my app will be rated for age 17+ users else 4+

I don't know what should I do? That website is for business only. It doesn't have anything wrong.

Comment: But does it allow for *unrestricted* web access -- meaning the user can visit any other page on the internet through your UIWebView?

Comment: Nope, I'm not providing any way of accessing any other web page. The user can only able to check out my given website.

Comment: Then it's not "unrestricted web access."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1**

If your application is for business only then I don't think age requirement 17+ will be an issue for you, right?

**#2**

If the `UIWebView` only displays the website and its sub-sites (so the user can not access other websites) then it is not considered *Unrestricted Web Access*.